# Best way to interact with MPU

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, c, uart

For the simplicity of the problem let's assume I'm using an Arduino.

If, for example, I have this code:

```
int x, y, z; // simple variables to store receive data into
int a, b, c; // some random parameters

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available()) {
    // here I want to change the parameters a, b and c on the fly
  }

  x = analogRead(0) * a;
  y = analogRead(1) * b;
  z = analogRead(2) * c;

  Serial.println("U%d V%d W%d",x, y, z)
}
```

As you can see, I'm sending a letter before the variables to know which value corresponds to which variable in another program on my PC, and be able to process the variable correctly.

Now if I want to change the parameters using my PC through USB, I have to send the same thing and split the data in the Arduino.

How to do this kind of thing?

Comment: "Better" in what sense? Does this work? If not what does it do that is different from what you expect?

Comment: other than that, pure 100% programming question: I think you'll need to learn what a `struct` really is and how to cast a pointer to void or char to a pointer to a struct.

Comment: ("for the simplicity of the problem let's assume I'm using an Arduino": Arduino *rarely* makes actual technical problems easier. It simplifies simple problems! Often, its architecture makes life a lot harder. The idea that `Serial` is for line-based text exchange is a pseudo-problem. It's not. The actual UART doesn't care what kind of data you send, and nothing, absolutely nothing, in your system cares about line breaks, or spaces, being in any way special. If you just sent integers as the bytes they are instead of converting them to text, there'd be nothing ambiguous about "splitting" them–

Comment: each `uint32_t` is 4 bytes, done. The fact that Arduino has a vast user code base and examples that make it seems like a UART is a text interface is what misleads you here; the fact that Arduino is a go-to platform is the *origin* of the problem; if your go-to platform wasn't as generous in string routines to begin with, you'd have learnt how to sent bytes before you learned how to send numerical data as strings.)

Comment: There is no best way for everyone. You should describe what is easier for you, and then do it.

Comment: At first glance the code seems OK to me (keeping in mind that I have some experience with low-level C code but have never used arduino). I have no idea what @MarcusMüller is getting at, but keep in mind that there are a diversity of attitudes and approaches. I would definitely advise you to AVOID casting pointers in C when possible. Usually it is not necessary. If it IS necessary I would only cast to and from void*. C++ is different than C in this regard. I don't know much about C++.

Comment: I just wanted to know if there is a standard way when someone wants to interact with a microprocessor through Serial, I just figured out that method myself, adding a letter before a value, how generally people achieve such thing? The simplest example is how does the TV know which button I pressed in the remote control.

Comment: There is no standard way. Sometimes people define a message format and send a stream of bytes as a message. You can look at NMEA 0183 message format as an example. But it doesn't have to be that complicated. Sometimes I find it convenient to send comma separated values so I can paste them into a spreadsheet program. But there is no one right way.

Comment: Adding time stamps to the data stream can often be helpful if you are going to graph stuff.

Comment: Then I can send a fix length message like "IDXXXX", for example I send "DE5421", and the microprocessor will split this buffer into two strings "DE" and "5421", check "DE" corresponds to which variable, convert the string into an unsigned integer then attribute that value to the DE variable.

Comment: @mkeith have a marked-as-helpful comment especially for "keep in mind that there are a diversity of attitudes and approaches"; what I was getting at is "you consider this to be a string splitting problem, but someone with a different background would be a bit confused why that is, as they would not be used to having `printf`-like functions on their microcontroller; switching perspective might help! Many people would just send the values, as they are bytes in memory, over the UART in the right order, and no splitting would be necessary."

Comment: @Marcus What do you mean by sending the values? if I want to modify one variable, then how the microprocessor knows that the value that he reserved corresponds to the variable I want?

Comment: easiest solution: your PC knows all three values (because you sent them before), so send them back all three and only modify the one you want to modify. More complicated solution: send an int that tells you which of the variables you want to modify, and then the value. MCU-side, a simple if/else if could be used to decide which variable to modify, – or

Comment: or you make something like a `int x, y, z; std::array variables{&x, &y, &z};`, and for receiving the indexing integer (0,1 or 2) do something like `unsigned int selector_byte = Serial.read(); if(selector_byte < variables.size()) Serial.readBytes(variables[selector_byte], sizeof(int));`

Comment: @MarcusMüller "I think you'll need to learn what a struct really is and how to cast a pointer to void or char to a pointer to a struct" And I think you need to learn to _never_ cast such a pointer to a pointer to struct :) You will get problems with alignment and [strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) both.  Additionally, padding bytes may be present, you may have different network endianess compared to CPU endianess and so on.

Comment: @Lundin agreed, that's why it's "learning" and not just "copy this: `struct_t* mystructureddata = (struct_t*)buffer;`"! if you can't guarantee the alignment, all you can do is memcpy onto an existing struct, unless you really want to parse; alignment, packing/padding and endianness are things you'd usually manage on the host to be "correct" for the embedded device. Just like if I build an ethernet frame, my processor needs to do the conversion network byte order (if necessary).

Comment: (really depends on the size of your embedded system; anything beyond a cortex-M can probably well use one of the well-defined low-parse/zero-parse binary serialization formats of the protobuf/capnproto/messagepack/flatbuffers… family. I'm pretty partial to the last one. But for a MCU, honestly, I'd have to trust the data coming from the host to be bit-wise equivalent to my on-MCU struct. Not too much magic, usually, and things like USB transfer content buffers often are conveniently reliably aligned.)

Comment: (actually, flatcc actively targets low-memory platforms, so it might just work on a cortex-M0, huh. that's convenient.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Except the strict aliasing part has nothing to do with binary equivalence but the compiler's internal type system. If you do unsupported casts and de-reference, then that's undefined behavior and may result in the wrong machine code getting generated. This was a big problem in the early 2000s on the gcc compiler, particularly when that one started to get used in embedded systems. It's still a problem to this day (on more compilers than gcc too), you can now and then provoke very strange things by doing a strict aliasing violation even on new compiler versions.

Comment: I don't see how you can violate aliasing rules if you receive a data struct via e.g. UART – that thing cannot contain pointers, right? And because the nature of the transfers, a "pointer to a buffer-contained struct" would also hardly be passed together with the raw pointer into the same region to some function

Comment: @MarcusMüller If you have placed the received data in some buffer `uint8_t buf[n]`, have some code `if(buf[0] == X) { do_stuff(); }`, then access by `structptr = (mystruct*)buf;`, change the binary values of `buf[0]` through some `structptr->member = 123;` and then again do `if(buf[0] == X} { do_stuff(); }`, the compiler is free to save the result from the first `if` check in a register, and then the second time check against that saved register value instead of re-reading `buf`. Since `buf` has evidently not changed since the last time, as far as the compiler knows. Undefined behavior.

Comment: @Lundin absolutely no question about that! But it would a) be a very … bold design to modify a struct you've received, and b) while this is *possible* to do, I'd hope people casting memory locations to struct pointers abhor from using the same memory any other way. But I clearly see the danger here. It's just like the Ethernet frame header example from above – that header doesn't "belong" to the reading code, the `struct*` cast really only serves not having to do something awkward like `struct header_t hdr; memcpy(&(hdr.length), buffer + offsetof(header_t, length), sizeof(uint16_t));` for

Comment: every member of `hdr` if the buffer has bit-by-bit same layout as `header_t`. Note that I still consider an RX buffer from hardware on a microcontroller essentially read-only. (you don't get the memory to have a large pool of RX buffers, so you need to hand back these buffers to e.g. the DMA engine sooner than you like, so you want to just read the values you care about and copy some payload data.)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Vertinhol:
As others in the comments have mentioned there are lots of standards. For very simple programs, make up your own. It is good practice.

The UART transfers data one byte at a time. Sometimes only 7-bits are valid but mostly it is 8.

Serial.println converts all data into character types which are single bytes for serial transfer.

There are many protocols that are used for data transmission. Depending on the complexity of your requirements you can implement one. I am not familiar with Arduino, so I do not know what choices that you have. Protocols often use "headers" that are 1 to several bytes of data that tell the receiver what to do with the rest of thes data. The data are often grouped into frames or packets. The topic perhaps should be formulated into a telecommunications question. This would be more appropriate for us unless the folks here can redirect you to a telecommunications stack exchange.

You need to research serial communication protocols for microprocessor systems.

Answer (score 1):

I made this code to this simple code that fits the best for me, there is room for optimizing it but it will do the trick.

```
#define ID_size 2
#define Value_size 2
#define Buffer_size Value_size+ID_size

#define ASCII_0 48

#define Parameter_A_ID "56"
#define Parameter_B_ID "A8"
#define Parameter_C_ID "PM"

void get_id(char* buf, char* local)
{
    for(int i=0;i<ID_size;i++)
    {
        *(local+i)=*(buf+i);
    }
    *(local+ID_size) = '\0';
}

void get_value(char* buf, char* local)
{
    for(int i=ID_size;i<Buffer_size;i++)
    {
        *(local+i-ID_size)=*(buf+i);
    }
    *(local + Value_size) = '\0';
}

int match(char* A1, char* A2)
{
    for(int i=0;(i<ID_size);i++)
    {
        if(*(A1+i) != *(A2+i))
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    
    return 1;
}

int convert_char_to_int(char* Number)
{
    int loc;
    
    loc = (*(Number + 1) - ASCII_0) + (*(Number) - ASCII_0) * 10;
    
    return loc;
}

void Attribute(char* Rx, int* P1, int* P2, int* P3)
{
    char ID[ID_size];
    char Value[Buffer_size - ID_size];
    get_id(Rx, ID);
    get_value(Rx,Value);
    if(match(ID,Parameter_A_ID) == 1)
    {
        *P1 = convert_char_to_int(Value);
    }
    else if(match(ID,Parameter_B_ID) == 1)
    {
        *P2 = convert_char_to_int(Value);
    }
    else if(match(ID,Parameter_C_ID) == 1)
    {
        *P3 = convert_char_to_int(Value);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int Parameter_A, Parameter_B, Parameter_C;
    char Buffer[Buffer_size + 1] ="A874";
    Attribute(Buffer, &Parameter_A, &Parameter_B, &Parameter_C);
    printf("%d %d",Parameter_A, Parameter_B);

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your inputs :D

Answer (score 1):

There is no best way.
To communicate with a microcontroller is to start with a good communication protocol.

Your example is a good start, but better is to have a byte (char) array containing
a start-byte, data-bytes, checksum and end-byte, so it's possible to resend if something gets corrupted.
I guess that you are fairly new to C, C++ and Arduino so I made a working Arduino example based on your code.

It uses a char array with three letters followed by numeric variables like
`:a1b22c333`

The example is well commented, and is a start to get you or others with reliable communication with a microcontroller. It absolutely not the only way!

Arduino Example:

```
//For this example send data to serial port as:
//a1b22c333 or A1224B12348C2 Case is ignored. A,B,C can be changed:
// use firstSend secondSend thirdSend to change
// Don't change the order, first a-value then b-value then c-value.
//3 values can be send. Don't use punctuation marks or spaces.

char serialbuffer[64]; //Max serial buffer = 64.
//In many serial monitors Newline character is automatically added with send or enter key
char endMarker = '\n'; //Newline character, choose whatever You want.
char firstSend = 'a'; // Case is ignored. Change if you like
char secondSend = 'b'; //Case is ignored. Change if you like
char thirdSend = 'c'; //Case is ignored. Change if you like 
int  receivedSize = 0; //Number of bytes to read.
ulong baudrate = 115200; //Change this to the baud-rate You want.

int x, y, z; //simple variables to store data into

//Get the index number of the literals returns index of literal (letter)
//or if not valid -1 .
int GetPos(char receive_Buffer[], char a) {
//Ignore case.
char b = (char)toUpperCase(a);
for (int i = 0; i < (int)(receivedSize); i++) {
    if ((receive_Buffer[i] == a) || (receive_Buffer[i] == b))
        return i;
}

return -1;
}

// returns true if data is available and valid, sets values for x,y,z.
bool Receive()
{
static bool valid = false;//Used to return true if new valid data is received.
//if nothing to read return false as fast as possible.
if (Serial.available() == 0) {
    valid = false;
    return valid;
}

int offsetA = -1;
int offsetB = -1;
int offsetC = -1;
receivedSize = Serial.readBytesUntil(endMarker, serialbuffer, 16);  //The end-marker is discarded from the serial buffer
//only run if there is data to read
if (receivedSize > 0) {
    char* receiveBuffer = new char[receivedSize]; //Create a dynamic array, we don't know how many char are received.   
    // fill receiveBuffer with the received data.
    for (int i = 0; i < receivedSize; i++)
    {
        receiveBuffer[i] = serialbuffer[i];
    }

    int indexA = GetPos(receiveBuffer, firstSend);
    int indexB = GetPos(receiveBuffer, secondSend);
    int indexC = GetPos(receiveBuffer, thirdSend);

    //Check if the received data has the right format
    //and get the positions of the literals(letters).
    if ((indexA > -1) && (indexB > -1) && (indexC > -1)) {
        offsetA = indexB - indexA;
        offsetB = indexC - indexB;
        offsetC = receivedSize - indexC;
    }
    else {
        //Handle error.         
        delete[] receiveBuffer;
        receiveBuffer = NULL;
        Serial.println("Data received i wrong format");
        Serial.end(); // Ends the serial communication once all data is received
        Serial.begin(baudrate); // Re-establishes serial communication , this causes deletion of anything previously stored in the buffer //or cache
        delay(100);//Short delay to wait for the serial port to open.           
        return false;
    }


    //Crate 3 dynamic arrays. we don't know how many positions are needed,
    // for this example we use positive numbers only
    //on Arduino an int = -32768 to 32767(1 to 5 positions) or -2147483648 to 2147483647(1 to 10 positions)
    char* bufferA = new char[offsetA];
    char* bufferB = new char[offsetB];
    char* bufferC = new char[offsetC];
    //fill buffers with numbers only.
    //Numbers for first value :
    for (size_t i = indexA; i < offsetA; i++) {
        bufferA[i] = receiveBuffer[i + 1];
    }
    //Numbers for second value:
    for (size_t i = indexB; i < offsetB + indexB; i++) {
        bufferB[i - indexB] = receiveBuffer[i + 1];
    }
    //Numbers for third value :
    for (size_t i = indexC; i < offsetC + indexC; i++) {
        bufferC[i - indexC] = receiveBuffer[i + 1];
    }
    //atoi returns char array to single integer.
    x = atoi(bufferA);
    y = atoi(bufferB);
    z = atoi(bufferC);
    //free allocated memory used by dynamic arrays
    delete[] receiveBuffer;
    receiveBuffer = NULL;
    delete[] bufferA;
    bufferA = NULL;
    delete[] bufferB;
    bufferB = NULL;
    delete[] bufferC;
    bufferC = NULL;
    Serial.end(); // Ends the serial communication once all data is received
    Serial.begin(baudrate); // Re-establishes serial communication.
    //this causes deletion of anything previously stored in the buffer //or cache
    delay(100); //small delay to wait for the port to open.
    valid = true;
}
else {
    valid = false;
    return valid;
}

return valid;
}

// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {
Serial.begin(baudrate);
delay(200);//Short delay to wait for the serial port to open.
Serial.println("<Arduino is ready>");
}

// the loop function runs over and over again until power down or reset
void loop() {
//run only if new valid data has arrived (Receive() returns bool.
if (Receive())
{
    Serial.print("Received x = ");
    Serial.println(x);
    Serial.print("Received y = ");
    Serial.println(y);
    Serial.print("Received z = ");
    Serial.println(z);
}
}
```

> Data sent: A1B22C320001
>
> result: Opening port Port open  Received x = 1
> Received y = 22 Received z = 320001

With micro-controllers, there is no memory manager.
Using and deleting dynamic arrays fragments the heap and You can run out of memory, so my example is not very useful.
I could make a new working example, not using dynamic arrays if requested
I hope this will help you and others,